# Why does JSON filter make empty Collection inside beans?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, filter

I have Collection of objects (beans, Hibernate one-to-many).
example:

```
class Small{
    private String field1;
    public String getField1(){
        return this.field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1){
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
class Big {
    Set<Small> list = new HashSet<Small>(0);
    public Set<Small> getList(){
        return this.list;
    }
    public void setField1(Set<Small> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}

List<Big> list = ....;/// Here I get a list of Big object;
JsonConfig jsonConfig=new JsonConfig();
jsonConfig.setJsonPropertyFilter(new PropertyFilter() {   
    public boolean apply(Object source, String name, Object value) {   
        if (!(name.equals("list")) {
            return true;   
        } else {   
            return false;   
        }   
    }   
}); 

JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(list , jsonConfig);
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

And in result I have next string:

```
[{"list":{}}]
```

Nothing inside list, but when I use:

```
JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(list);
```

instead

```
JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(list , jsonConfig);
```

json show me all information.

How can I use `jsonConfig` and get information from inner collection?

Comment: Please don't use `<br />` in your posts next time.

Comment: OK, thanks for advice, it was my first post here.